# PHP group array items where max sums equals

Tags: php, arrays

```
$array = [2,3,4,5];
```

I want group array elements where elements sums can be max 5, and requirement is to have less as possible groups:

```
[
[2,3],
[4],
[5],
]
```

how to do that grouping programmatically

Comment: And you are asking exactly what?

Comment: @AleksG how to do that grouping programmatically

Comment: Very unclear: What happens here? `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`  or is this a special case? Or `[1,2,2,3,4,5]`?

Comment: usually this is called "clustering"

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions yes sure array can have more keys, grouping will be done same as in example

Comment: Then can become very complex. If all possible combination are needed. `[[1,2,2],[1,4],[3,2]]`

Comment: ***"where elements sums can be max 5"*** which elements?! the 1st and 4th? the 2nd and 5th ? your question's very unclear .

Comment: @PedroLobito you can combine all elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can use something like:

```
$array = [2,3,4,5,3,1,3,5,2,2,8];
$results = [];

for( $x=0; $x < count($array); $x++ )
{
    if( $x < count($array) - 1 ){
        if ( $array[$x] + $array[$x + 1] <= 5 )
        {
            array_push( $results,  [$array[$x], $array[$x + 1]] );
            $x++;
        } else if( $array[$x] <= 5 ){
            array_push( $results,  [$array[$x]] );
        }
    } else if( $array[$x] <= 5 ){
        array_push( $results, [$array[$x]] );
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
        )

)
```

---

[php example](http://ideone.com/EwPws8)

Comment: are you sure that it will work with negative values?

Comment: I didn't test the code with negative numbers because the OP didn't mention it.